# HTML5 video tag autoplay not working in Chrome (but OK in jsfiddle!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm trying to do a simple video with autoplay on our homepage (http://froy.com). Nothing fancy. Everything works smoothly in Firefox and even IE.

However, the autoplay does not activate on Chrome. I have tried in incognito with no extensions and issue persists. Weird part is, trying the code out on jsfiddle works! Additionally, I see similar video tag used at other websites working as well.

In fact, I went through bit by bit adding different parts of the entire homepage's code to jsfiddle (html, css, javascript) to try to isolate the issue - no luck. I'm at a loss and any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code:

```html
<video preload="auto" autoplay loop muted width="100%" height="auto" style="margin-top:-25px" >
     <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0220/3498/files/Video_Slider_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0220/3498/files/Video_Slider_1.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Does this have something to do with my javascript? If so, why is jsfiddle not picking this up when I include scripts in it?

Comment: It failed for me, then worked when I tried it in incognito, and then it worked when I tried again in non-incognito. :/

Comment: Or maybe it was just very slow to load?

Comment: No, it definitely has to do with incognito. Are you sure you tested it with no extensions interfering? I see 404 errors in the network tab in my non-incognito window for both formats of the video. If I load in an incognito window, that fails to load the mp4 file but loads the webm file. And IF I LEAVE THE INCOGNITO WINDOW OPEN, and reload in the non-incognito window, then the webm file succeeds there.

Comment: And then if I clear the cache, reload the page in non-incognito mode, and disable AdBlock and Disconnect, then it succeeds in loading the mp4 file. So I suspect Chrome is not always completely isolating the incognito window from the extensions.

Comment: I think there is something very strange or inconsistent about Chrome. Hoping that a new version will provide a fix. The code itself is so straightforward... I have no extensions running in incognito. I've since changed the code on the homepage to run on a setTimeout() instead of the autoplay attribute to 'cheat' for Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the same code which you are using, just the video is served from my server, and everything is working fine.

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay loop muted width="100%" height="auto" style="margin-top:-25px" >
     <source src="http://www.example.com/clip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="http://www.example.com/clip.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Google Chrome Version: Version 38.0.2125.111 m